# Alternative to ctor/inventory for when compiling to wasm?

Tags: rust, rust-macros, webassembly

The `ctor` crate doesn't support web assembly currently, [although there is active discussion about how to fix this](https://github.com/rustwasm/wasm-bindgen/issues/1216).

Although I am well aware of the issues associated with static initialization coming from C++, being able to register things with a factory at startup is a very handy capability, and is necessary to avoid violating the DRY principle in a lot of cases. Without it every time you want to add a new possibility to your factory you have to add a separate line of code to `main()`, possibly more lines if you need to import your new function. This quickly gets tedious.

I am wondering if it is possible to build something equivalent (at least when everything you want to register is concentrated inside a single crate) using a procedural attribute macro and `build.rs`. The macro would be used to mark the functions that I want to register, and it's implementation would save the module paths (`"crate::your::registered_function"`) of those functions off to the side somewhere in a file but otherwise just be a passthrough. Then `build.rs` would generate a function that calls all the functions listed in the file, and I would have `main()` call that one function by hand.

- Is there a different trick that would work instead?
- Does an implementation of this already exist somewhere I could use as a reference?
- How would the procedural macro actually generate the module path for the function to be called? There is `module_path!` but if invoked from inside the definition of the procedural macro it will give the module path for the macro, not the module path associated with what the TokenStream is going to expand into. The macro could generate a call to `module_path!` but that won't evaluate until later when the final program is run.

Comment: Sorry if this is a dumb question, but is it absolutely essential to initialise your statics at startup?  Can't you get away with `lazy_static` or similar?

Comment: I don't think lazy_static allows you to modify _another_ static, to subscribe to a list of plugins for example.

Comment: What's wrong with adding an extra line to `main()`? I don't think this is a violation of DRY. It's one thing to link with code, another to actively request usage of that code. Using `main()` to wire dependencies together is a common pattern in DI.

Comment: When you have dozens of structs and functions, it can be very hard to remember to add them to the right place. I also find it much clearer to have "everything together" when adding the dependency. That way if I remove the module for example I can just remove the entire file and everything will be working.

Comment: @Thomas This is just for linking. If you want to list available plugins, modules, etc, they need to be registered somewhere central.